# Case sensitivity with file names in VS Code and Windows Git

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm having an issue with `VS Code v1.26.1` on `Windows 10`. I cloned a repository where, in the same directory, it has file names with the same name but different cases for example: `filename.ext` and `FileName.ext`.

`VS Code` thinks that these are the same file with a change, therefore it is showing them in the Source Control, but when I discard the changes it just changes the names back to the other case + it won't stash or stage them.

I have tried the `git config core.ignorecase false` and `git config --global core.ignorecase false` commands but it doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried changing it to true and back to false.

Anyone had/having this issue and found a work around for this?

PS: I cannot change the file names to something else. These file names MUST stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late answer, but [Git and Case Sensitivity](https://aqandrew.com/blog/git-and-case-sensitivity/#solution) solved the problem for me.

My project wouldn't compile because it was looking for `app.js` instead of the file's actual name `App.js`. I renamed the file in VSCode and the project compiled. However, after every commit, `App.js` reverted to `app.js`.

To force git to detect the change I used [git-mv](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv).

```
git mv app App
```

According to the post author:

> The tracked file or folder you want to recapitalize has to be
> explicitly renamed using a Git command. git mv works the same as mv,
> except it informs Git that a file or folder has been renamed by
> immediately staging the change.

Answer (score 1):

in April 2018, NTFS became [fully case-sensitive](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10) (on demand).

Before checking out your project, run this in elevated command prompt:

```
fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo git_project_root enable
```

It seems, though, that Visual Studio must be fixed to work with such folders correctly. I have not tried Visual Studio Code on these.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 steps rename works fine for me.

```
git mv OriginalFolder tempfolder
git mv tempfolder originalfolder
git commit -m "renamed folder to lowercase"
```